# Why won't this CSS sheet render?

Tags: html, css

This is kind of embarrassing but I cannot for some reason get his `CSS` to work with my `HTML`. I don't Know if I am not navigating through the directory correctly or what. The `HTML` is loading fine in the browser but `CSS` is not. Here is an image of my directory and the code I'm using in the header:

[image]

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="staging.mesantos.com/_/css/desktop.css" type="text/css">
```

desktop.css:

```
    body {
    background-color: red;
    font-family: Rokkitt, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Are you certain the file is not being loaded by the browser, or could it be that the styles contained within aren't being rendered as you expect them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't really tell from the screenshot but isn't the index.html file already in the staging.mesantos.com directory? If so, you can take that part out of the href.

Comment: Yeah, the href needs fixing. Either prepend `//` or remove the hostname because at the moment it looks like a sub-directory.